# Third party API endpoint blocked by CORS policy for localhost in React fetch

Tags: reactjs, cors, fetch-api

Trying to fetch [Openwhyd Data Export API](https://openwhyd.github.io/openwhyd/API#openwhyd-data-export-api) endpoint https://openwhyd.org/hot?format=json using [React with JS fetch()](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html), but it doesn't run on localhost:3000, it gives the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://openwhyd.org/hot?format=json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

If there is a way to fix from within the React App?

Part of my code that fetches the API:

```
  // fetch the data from the API endpoint
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://openwhyd.org/hot?format=json'})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result);
      }
    )
  }
```

I tried using `mode: "no-cors"`, but then the respose from the API fetch() is not usable for data output.

OS: maciOS Mojave Version 10.14.5
Browser: Chrome Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: See the *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* section of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/441757. The gist of it is, you can either set up a CORS proxy of your own, or else you can change the URL in your fetch request like this: `fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://openwhyd.org/hot?format=json')`

Answer (score 0):

If their API does not provide the [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and their API does not support JSONP then your only option is to proxy the request through your own server. In this scenario you would add a endpoint to your backend application that makes the request to openwhyd. Then you would make all your requests from your front end to your backend.  Alternatively, you could setup a nginix/apache in front of your application to do the proxy for you.